# stop popoverViewController resignFirstResponder after dismissed

Tags: ios, ios6, uipopovercontroller, first-responder

I am using a uitableview containing multiple rows, and each row contains two UITextFields side by side. let's say TextField1, TextField2. When a user taped on TextField1, and start typing, a popoverViewController shows up for suggestions. When the user tap on a suggestion from the popoverViewController, the popover dismissed (this is what i want), then the keyboard dismissed as well (this is not what i want). if now the user tap on TextField2, the keyboard comes up.

I want to keep the keyboard up because the user needs to input in TextField2.
How can i make this happen?

really appreciated.

Comment: I have this same problem when moving between UITextFields programmatically. The keyboard performs the dismiss animation, and then the animation to reappear - distracting and unwanted.  Significantly, this issue is new and specific to iOS 6 - the keyboard does *not* dismiss momentarily under iOS 5, as intended.